# USB sniffing using a USB module in a micro controller

Tags: usb, microcontroller

Is it possible to capture a USB data from a usb communication between two devices by just tapping the lines  and giving it to another controller with USB modules ?

To explain better A is communicating with B . C knows what interface they are using and in what endpoints  they are communicating . Intension of C is to just listen what they are communicating. And C don’t want A and B to know that he is listening to their communication.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is basically "is it possible to build USB hardware analyzer/sniffer". As there are sniffers on the market, the answer to this question is yes.

One possible approach (if you are not *that much* interested in the physical layer) is to use USB PHY (e.g. Microchip USB3343 for USB 2.0) in passive mode. In such scenario the USB PHY does translate the USB signalling to ULPI. Then you can process the ULPI data to extract the USB packets. If you are interested in High Speed (or faster, e.g. USB 3.0 SuperSpeed) then pretty much the only viable approach is to use FPGA to do the processing.

If you are interested in seeing what kind of effort is needed to achieve USB 2.0 sniffing in hardware using the USB PHY approach, then check out the [OpenVizsla](http://openvizsla.org/) project.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it is possible.

It depends on the features of the USB module of the microcontroller. If it has something like a pure "listener" or "tap" mode, it should work. But I'm not aware of any USB module capable of this. This means nothing as there are so many different microcontrollers.